# Get Mysite Profile pictures using jquery

Tags: 2007, jquery

Using Sharepoint 2007
Have JQuery and SPServices.js available.

I need to be able to gather profile pictures (or just the URL whichever is easier) from a users MySite.

It will be a dynamic list of users and their Windows Login will be in the list. The requirements only allow me to use HTML which limits what kind of code I can use.

I know I can gather the current users profile picture with this javascript implementing JQuery and SPServices.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery/jquery.SPServices.js></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Picture", debug: false});
    </script>
```

I just wanted to know if anyone knew how to gather the pictures from a list of multiple users.

Sorry im a newbie with SharePoint.

Thanks!

Comment: Brad, could you please add more detail to your question including an explanation of all the part and pieces that need to work together?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just change the person group column you're using in the list to display the user's picture instead of their name? (List Settings -> Click your column -> Toggle drop down box)

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify properly. The dynamic link is not in SharePoint. It is in a SQL-Server Database

Comment: Brad, I think you need to explain your requirements better based on that comment.